# Javascript link to the <select> id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

My problem is im working in prestashop(1.6.1.9) CMS pages, im not allowed to put any script into the cms pages source code.(im not using iframe for this, its not a solution)..

So i have an dropdown menu , where each link on the drop down links to a certain page. I want to use a java-script function to do this.

But because i cant call java-script on the page like this example,

```
<select id="selectdrops" name="newurl"  onchange="menu_goto(this.form)  ">
    <option value="/index.html">Home</option>
    <option value="/feedback.html">Feedback</option>
    <option value="/links.html">Related Links</option>
</select>
```

i wish to make my javascript focus on the dropdown 'ID' if thats possible?

Removing : **menu_goto(this.form)** i would like to still accomplish the targeted links by maybe focusing on the select "ID".

My .js looks like this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on('change', '#dropSelectAbout', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        menu_goto();
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a").click(function(event) {
            alert(event.target.id);
        });
    }); 

});

function menu_goto( menuform )
{
   var baseurl = window.document.location.protocol + '//' + window.document.location.host;
   selecteditem = menuform.newurl.selectedIndex ;
   newurl = menuform.newurl.options[ selecteditem ].value ;
   if (newurl.length != 0) {
     location.href = baseurl + newurl ;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest making the following changes;

```
$(document).on('change', '#selectdrops', function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       menu_goto(e.target.value);
    });
})

function menu_goto( newurl ) {
    var baseurl = window.document.location.protocol + '//' + window.document.location.host;

    if (newurl.length != 0) {
        window.location = baseurl + newurl ;
    }
}
```

Removed: (the script below removed because it targets all the < a > tags on the page which creates an pop-up dialog message when links are clicked, so the function on top was only script needed to focus on my dropdown where id="selectdrops" )

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a").click(function(event) {
           alert(event.target.id);
        });
    });
```

`e.target.value` will give you the selected option therefore you can pass the value directly into your `menu_goto` function. 
`location` does not have a `ref` property therefore use `window.location` if the intention to redirect to the newly constructed url.

Comment: YOU ARE THE TRUE HERO ,WORKED , THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect on change (not after a button click) you can use this script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on('change', '#selectdrops', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            menu_goto(this);
        });

});

function menu_goto( menuform )
{
    if(menuform == null)
        return;

    newurl = $(menuform).val() ;

    if (newurl.length != 0) {
        location.href = baseUri + newurl ;
    }
}
```

You can use the baseUri variable that Prestashop uses to get the store url. This works better for subdomains.
Then set the links in the select without the / (it's already in the baseUri).

EDIT:
To use a button click:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on('click', '#golink', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            menu_goto();
        });

});

function menu_goto()
{
    var menuform = $('#selectdrops');

    if(menuform == null)
        return;

    newurl = menuform.val() ;

    if (newurl.length != 0) {
        location.href = baseUri + newurl ;
    }
}
```

in this case the button link to execute must have the id golink.

Comment: Well thanks for that, but yea i want to click on an option and then it should redirect me to the corresponding page which is in the Value attribute.Maybe i should give the <option> tag also an id, i dont know. But i wish to direct my JS to this select , and on the click of any <option> that it would redirect me to the option Value(/index.html) attribute

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to pass the form as a parameter of the `menu_goto` function (also selector was false. Here is corrected code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('change', '#selectdrops', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    menu_goto(this.form);
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function(event) {
      alert(event.target.id);
    });
  });

});

function menu_goto(menuform) {
  var baseurl = window.document.location.protocol + '//' + window.document.location.host;
  selecteditem = menuform.newurl.selectedIndex;
  newurl = menuform.newurl.options[selecteditem].value;
  if (newurl.length != 0) {
    location.href = baseurl + newurl;
  }
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <select id="selectdrops" name="newurl">
    <option value="/index.html">Home</option>
    <option value="/feedback.html">Feedback</option>
    <option value="/links.html">Related Links</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks man, i tried this, when the menu drops and i select one of the <option> tags , just nothing happens, could it be because its not triggered on an click event?

Comment: Trying this solution outside your context works fine, event is fired and page changes (like in above example). It may be due to other things in prestashop. Maybe all this is in a iframe, and you are changing the location of the iframe. Maybe prestashop is not letting you change location. You should put a breakpoint in inspector at the location change line and you'll be sure.